# Whats wrong with my cte and insert command

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g, common-table-expression

Its just a basic cte with inner join and insert command dont know what is the mistake I did please help

My table t1

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
3   C
```

My table t2

```
ID  Name
1   A
2   B
```

What I'm trying to do is, inner join two table and take unmatched records. Insert the unmatched record into table t2. This is what I wrote

```
with scd(scdid,scdname)
as
(select t1.id as scdid, t1.name as scdname from t1 where t1.id not in (select t1.id from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id))
insert into t2(id,name) select scd.scdid, scd.scdname from scd;
```

Something went wrong it says

```
SQL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
```

Please help, it must be simple mistake i guess

Edit: apologies for the mistake, yes I'm using Oracle server.

Comment: Oracle error on SQL Server?  Are you on Oracle, or using a linked server?

Comment: @Amjath . . . You should tag your question correctly.  If it is for Oracle, remove the sql-server tag and add an Oracle tag.

Comment: @JiggsJedi yes, I'm sorry i did it in a hurry

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes I'm sorry i did it in a hurry, edited the op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the query:

```
with scd(scdid, scdname) as
      (select t1.id as scdid, t1.name as scdname
       from t1
       where t1.id not in (select t1.id from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id)
      )
insert into t2(id, name)
    select scd.scdid, scd.scdname
    from scd;
```

This query looks syntactically correct for SQL Server.  However, you have an Oracle error.  Try writing the query as:

```
insert into t2(id, name)
    select t1.id as scdid, t1.name as scdname
    from t1
    where t1.id not in (select t1.id from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id);
```

Or better yet as:

```
insert into t2(id, name)
    select t1.id as scdid, t1.name as scdname
    from t1
    where t1.id not in (select t2.id from t2);
```

Note that the Oracle syntax for a CTE with an `insert` is to place the `with` *after* the `insert`.  However, a CTE is not needed for this.

EDIT:  In Oracle syntax:

```
insert into t2(id, name)
with scd(scdid, scdname) as
      (select t1.id as scdid, t1.name as scdname
       from t1
       where t1.id not in (select t1.id from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id)
      )
    select scd.scdid, scd.scdname
    from scd;
```

In Oracle, the `with` statement is part of a `select`.

Comment: Thanks, can you write one with cte please